# Query all connected ancestors and descendants in a self referencing table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, self-referencing-table

Suppose I have a table 'prlines' with a self relation on adjacent records:

```sql
id | prev_id
------------
1  | NULL
2  | NULL
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 5
```

I want to get all connected IDs (previous/next) of a certain record. For example:

```sql
SELECT `prev_id` FROM `prlines` ... WHERE id = 5;
```

Should produce this output:

```sql
prev_id
-------
3
1
6
```

What I am doing currently is making a while loop in python that generates multiple queries to follow the relationship for each record. Any ideas to achieve this in a single mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte:

```
with recursive cte(p, c, f) as (
   select p.*, p.prev_id = 5 from prlines p where p.id = 5 or p.prev_id = 5
   union all
   select p.*, c.f from cte c join prlines p on case when c.f then p.prev_id = c.p else p.id = c.c end
)
select case when f then p else c end prev_id from cte where c is not null order by f;
```

Output:

| prev_id |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a96120c267e6901c179579bf2d0341f3).

Comment: Very nice, however can it crawl forward as well? it only goes forward one step. If I add a new row (id:7, prev_id:6) it should be included, but it is not.